# Using reflection to find DynamicMethods

Tags: c#, reflection, reflection.emit

I'd like to somehow find all `DynamicMethods` in my current context, consider that I have the following method and delegate:

```
public delegate double DivideInvoker(int a, int b);
public DivideInvoker CreateInvoker()
{
    Type[] methodArguments = { 
                        typeof(int), 
                        typeof(int)
                    };

    DynamicMethod division = new DynamicMethod(
            "Division",
            typeof(double),
            methodArguments,
            typeof(MyMethodCreator));

    ILGenerator il = division.GetILGenerator();
    il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
    il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_1);
    il.Emit(OpCodes.Div);
    il.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

    var divideIt = (DivideInvoker)division.CreateDelegate(typeof(DivideInvoker));

    return divideIt;
}
```

If I were to do: `var divideIt = CreateInvoker();`, can I somehow use reflection to find the dynamic method method?

According to MSDN the above dynamic method will be static and once it's not used anymore it will be disposed by the GC, I am just using this to play around with reflection.

I've tried getting all types in the executing assembly and listing all the methods on them, but I can't find anything on the `DynamicMethod`.

Any ideas?

Comment: Clarification: He wants to find all created DynamicMethods that have not yet been garbage collected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DivideInvoker invoker = CreateInvoker();
MethodInfo method = invoker.Method;
// method will contain the MethodInfo of the Division dynamic method
// so you could use reflection on it
```

Comment: I don't want to use my instance of it, is there any other way?

Comment: Obviously if it's garbage collected it only exists in that DyanmicMethod instance thus you won't find it in a loaded module. So the only way to reflect it is having a reference to the instance.